# Is it foolish not to use DirectShow as the basis of a CUDA video processing pipeline for Windows?

Tags: video, cuda, directshow, opencl, video-processing

When building a CUDA oriented video processing pipeline to run exclusively on windows,there are  two approaches.

You either use DirectShow or you don't.

The decision not to use directshow is also the decision to code every portion of the pipeline yourself.

This includes reading, parsing,  processing and rendering or retransmission of the stream. if if

With DirectShow, however, you gain access to a fairly large body of existing components that are quite capable of doing some portion of the pipeline's work.

This means you may focus your dev process on coding one or more DirectShow sources, filters, or renderers which use CUDA to encapsulate any novel or otherwise unavailable  processing.

And as a result of adopting a component based architecture, you are in a good position to develop alternate implementations i.e. OpenCL. without having to touch the  other parts of the pipeline.

Are there any liabilities to DirectShow participation that warrant the extra work involved to develop and maintain the pieces that are not CUDA specific?

Comment: If the assertion "run exclusively on windows" is not going to change during your project, I do not see anything bad enough in DirectShow that could justify the cost of re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't already, it might be useful to have a look at the "cudaDecodeD3D9" demo in the NVidia GPU SDK (CUDA SDK). It decodes and renders a video without DirectShow (using CUDA and DirectX9). Similarly, there's a "cudaDecodeOpenGL" demo if you prefer.